# Printing html popup window using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how do i print a html page which is getting opened in a popup ?

what I tried is :

```
function printFile() {
        var w = window.open('test.htm', 'name', 'width=200,height=200');
        w.focus();
        w.print();
    }
```

but the above code always prints about:blank.

Comment: it's working fine for me firefox.... what's your browser?

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for the window to load:

```
function printFile() {
        var w = window.open('test.htm', 'name', 'width=200,height=200');
        w.onload = w.print;
        w.focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check your **test.htm** page it should be **in same folder**

i have check your code it's run perfectly.